# Construction of the subrectangles in Palka's proof that $\int\limits_{\partial R}f(z)dz=0$ when $f$ is analytic and $R$ is a rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, complex-integration

This is from Palka's *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory*, Chapter 5, lemma 1.1:

> If a function $f$ is analytic in an open set $U$, then $\int\limits_{\partial R}f(z)dz = 0$ for every closed rectangle $R$ in $U$.

My specific question is how do we know what Palka claims about the diagonal and perimeter of the divided subrectangles when the discussion has been around the integral of an analytic function $f$ over the boundaries of rectangles.

Palka begins his proof by first arguing why given a closed rectangle $R$ in $U$, one can subdivide it into four congruent rectangles $R_1^{i}, i = 1,2,3,4$ such that if $I = \int\limits_{\partial R}f(z)dz$ then for some $i = 1,2,3,4$ we have that $|I^i_1|\geq 4^{-1}|I|$, where $I^i_1 = \int_{\partial R_1^i}f(z)dz$. Then by induction Palka argues that we can divide the original rectangle $R$ even further so that at the $n$th step we have $|I_n| \geq 4^{-n}|I|$, where the subscript has been removed (as we've already argued about the existence in terms of the four starting subrectangles).

Then, Palka states that

> Let $d_n$ designate the length of the diagonal of the rectangle $R_n$, and let $L_n$ be its perimeter. If $d$ and $L$ represent the corresponding quantities for the original rectangle $R$, then **by construction** $d_n = 2^{-n}d, L_n = 2^{-n}L$.

What I don't understand is that what is the construction he is talking about, in the sense that to this point the chain of subrectangles has been formed with a condition on the integral of $f$ over the boundaries of the original and subrectangles. Therefore it is unclear to me how we know that at each step of the division procedure, the diagonal and perimeter of the original rectangle are halved.

Comment: i haven't read Palka but this looks like a standard proof.  Have you been able to verify the claim of halving the diagonal and perimeter after the very first subdivision?  If so, then the claim 'by construction' follows immediately by induction.  If not, what did you do / where did you get stuck?

Comment: @user8675309 I have not been able to verify the claim for the very first subdivision. The reason is that the only two pieces of information I have are 1.) $f$ is analytic on $U$, 2.) $|I_1| \geq 4^{-1}|I|$, and I don't know how to connect these two facts to the perimeter and the diagonal. So, I have not tried anything as I don't know what to try.

Comment: How do you interpret the statement of -- subdividing a rectangle into 4 congruent rectangles?  I infer he means bisecting each line segment (edge) and inserting a dot (vertex) there, then drawing a line segment (edge) from left to right to connect a pair of the new dots and a drawing a vertical line segment to connect another pair of new dots.  Result: 4 congruent rectangles.

Comment: @user8675309 You are right, it is quite obvious when you think about it clearly for little while.